# What does "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" mean?

Tags: python-3.5

I'm trying to create an application in Python 3.5 and i use spaces all the time for indentation, but the editor print out "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" when it comes to

```
print("This car has "+str(self.odometer_reading)+" miles on it.")
```

How can i solve this problem? I'm a beginner in programming. I would be glad if i could get some overall tips on my code.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
    #初始化描述汽车的属性
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
        self.odometer_reading=0

    def read_odometer(self):
    #打印一条指出汽车里程的消息
        print("This car has "+str(self.odometer_reading)+" miles on it.")

my_new_car.read_odometer()
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that some of your code you've indented by pressing space and some of the code has been indented by pressing tab. You can tell which one is in use for a certain line by pressing backspace on the insert and if it deletes approx 4 characters worth of space it was an indent, otherwise it was a space. I would recommend that you either pick space or tab to indent your code then be consistent. To get your code working I would recommend you simplify remove all indentation then use either space or tab to indent.

Answer (score 0):

Many editors support the display of the indentation mark and spaces.

Turn them on, you will see what the interpreter is talking about.

Its not possible to tell from your code displayed here. They have all be converted to spaces by syntax highlighter.